# When using git, is there a easy way to when reverting, deleting files that weren't added to the repository since the last commit?

Tags: git, version-control

I'd like to know if there's a easy (built-in) way to when reverting to an old commit, delete all the files that were created since that commit, even if they weren't added to the repository.

Let's say I have a directory `D` and have made a commit `C` over `D`. If I now add to directory `D` a new file `F` and wish to revert do `C`, `F` won't be deleted from the directory.

Is there any easy way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your example, but this command:

```
git clean -xdf <directory>
```

**will remove all untracked and ignored files and subdirectories** from `<directory>`. (Make sure you really mean it!) The `-x` makes it delete ignored files, and the `-d` makes it delete directories - remove those if you don't want to do that. The `-f` is required for it to do anything, since it's so scary - you can also use `-n` for a "dry run".

In combination with `git reset --hard`, this can be used to get you to *exactly* the state of the current commit.

There's no way to make Git do this automatically, since it'd be absolutely terrifying - you might forget to commit a file, then blow it away.

Comment: From a preliminary test that seems exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @devoured: Glad I got it right! Just be very careful with your new toy.